# Joining Three Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with joining three tables, this image shows the fields and table names.

Extract from database:

```
voting table
id name  closed date       votes_up votes_down
 4 29192      0 1467441761       32         14
21 14427      0 1467450299        1          0
20 14464      0 1467449751        0          0
14 27345      0 1467447075        0          0
 9 27329      0 1467443096        1          0


games table
id    id_gamepressure id_gamepressure2 title
 256             8228            10759 Yu-Gi-Oh! World Championship 2007
 512             2520             9294 Boulder Dash Rocks!
 768            10155            12664 SpongeBob vs. The Big One. Beach Party Cook-Off
1024             9587             8484 Nacho Libre

images table
id    id_game id_gamepressure filename 
30695   10001          173814 10001_deca-sports_11792.jpg
30690   10001          173819 10001_deca-sports_1524.jpg
30692   10001          173817 10001_deca-spoets_3551.jpg
30694   10001          173815 10001_deca-sportss_572.jpg
30693   10001          173816 10001_deca_sports_8866.jpg
30691   10001          113818 10001_deca-sports_9417.jpg
```

Basically I want to be able to find the most popular games via from the "voting table" using the field "votes_up" then linking matching it with the "games table" and finally with the "images table"

I want to display it in list form, sorted by the highest voted game.

like this:

1. game title (rating) (image)

Comment: please add your table definition

Comment: show us what you have done

Comment: you dont need to join on them then, you need to count the votes in the select with a sub query and then order on that value.  Assuming votes `"voting table"` is a separate table and not numeric value that is.  Your gonna have to aggregate the votes for each game, essentially.

Comment: Why is it name and not game_id or ( id_game ) ? just curious...

Comment: added link to my database

Comment: its a voting script purchased from codecanyon, its default

Comment: That's stupid, id get my money back ...  I dont remember if you can do correlated sub querys in the select clause, I prolly forgot more code them most people ever learn lol

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I dont know the actual table names from your image.  Or what fields you want.

```
SELECT
   g.id,
   i.id   //or whatever fields you want.
FROM
   games AS g
INNER JOIN
   images AS i
ON
   g.id = i.id_game
LEFT JOIN
   votes AS v
ON
     g.id = v.name
ORDER BY 
   v.votes_up
DESC
```

In this case as votes is already a sum you dont have to count them like I was thinking,  ( votes would be 1 row per vote, that is what I was thinking )

Id use a left join, but I supose as you want the most up voted game it wouldn't really matter.

make sure the ids are indexs as well as the vote counts or sorting will kill the performance.

Comment: I tried it and getting this error. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id //or whatever fields you want.
FROM
games AS g
INNER JOIN
images AS ' at line 3

Comment: Removed the // and still getting this...SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id
FROM
games AS g
INNER JOIN
images AS i
ON
g.id = i.id_game
LEFT ' at line 3